# Do I really need to install cloud sdk if I have already installed eclipse plugin?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to start developing with google-cloud tools. I have seen three main products:

- Android IDE
- Plugin for Eclipse.
- Cloud SDK.

Do I need install the cloud sdk even if I have already installed the plugin for eclipse?
How is the colaboration between Cloud SDK and Eclipse plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Cloud SDK covers many of the functionalities offered by the Google Cloud Platform such as Google Cloud Storage, Compute Engine APIs, BigQuery.

As you mention the Eclipse Plugin I guess you want to develop Java applications for the Google App Engine platform. In that case, the Cloud SDK wouldn't be much useful for you, but the App Engine Java SDK.

This one is already downloaded by the Eclipse Plugin.

In addition, once you're working in a project, you may click the secondary button and choose the Google menu to install additional Google libraries such the ones mentioned before in the Cloud SDK.

So *the short answer would be no*.

Comment: Thank you very much! ... I'm trying to develop a simple mobile application with an App Engine backend just for learn the basics in android development!